# What form am I looking for? Display data in table with events

Tags: c#, winforms

Total noob here, just playing around with C# (which is very cool btw).

Anyways, I need to display some information in a table. I have to have the ability to set the content of the rows and cols dynamicly using the code and one field in the table has to trigger an event in C#.

```
Filename #1         Click here to download
Filename #2         Click here to download
```

You get the idea `Click here to download` should trigger an event in C#. What kind of form type am I looking for? I've looked at almost all of them, but I can't figure out which one is the one best suited for this.

Using "Windows Form Application" btw.

Comment: It's called a `Control`. A `Form` is the "Window" you put `Control`s on.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @ispiro :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataGridView` control is basically what you are describing.  The `DataGridView` has a LinkColumn type that acts like an HTML link.  You just handle the `CellContentClick` event and determine which cell the user clicked on:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { ReadOnly = true });
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewLinkColumn());

  dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
  dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "File #1";
  dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "Click here";

  dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellContentClick);
}

void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) {
    MessageBox.Show("Downloading " + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks excellent. Have to try it out later today. Thanks for detailed example!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750972.aspx)s. They provide a way to display a table of elements, and to listen to click events.